# Official webrtc source contains multiple copies of header files

Tags: android, webrtc

Following the instructions at http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/android, I managed to download and build webrtc code for Android. Now I am looking at using the header files/libraries in my Android project.

The problem is that the header files for webrtc are defined at two different places:

```
./src/webrtc/
./src/chromium/src/third_party/webrtc/
```

Further, the header files are not identical. For example,`module_common_types.h`under chromium defines a class called VideoFrame that is not present in`./src/webrtc/modules/interface/module_common_types.h` file.

Why this discrepancy?

It appears our non-Android applications are using the webrtc header files present under chromium. I too would have to use these files. However, I am not sure if `ninja`built`./src/out_android_armeabi-v7a/Release/obj/webrtc/libwebrtc.a`using the first header set or the second one.

Would appreciate any feedback that you may have. Regards.

Comment: You may get a better response for this on the webrtc mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/discuss-webrtc

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out to me. I did get a better response from the mailing list. Regards.